# AWS Cloudformation, best way to get values from keys with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I have a Cloudformation template with that defines the following output values:

```
Outputs:
  AccessKeyForUser:
    Value:
      !Ref CFNKeys
  SecretAccessKeyForUser:
    Value: !GetAtt CFNKeys.SecretAccessKey
```

In Python 3 with boto3, I currently get the output values this way:

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
cf_resource = session.resource('cloudformation')
stack = cf_resource.Stack(stackname)

code_commit_access_key = next(filter(lambda x: x['OutputKey'] == 'AccessKeyForUser', stack.outputs))['OutputValue']
code_commit_access_secret = next(filter(lambda x: x['OutputKey'] == 'SecretAccessKeyForUser', stack.outputs))['OutputValue']
```

I think that's not the best way. Is there a better way to get the output values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you actually want is to have a dictionary you can query for all keys you're interested in. So let's just create one using a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), which is probably the shortest while still pythonic way to implement this:

```python
cf_resource = boto3.resource("cloudformation")
stack = cf_resource.Stack(stackname)

outputs = {output["OutputKey"]: output["OutputValue"] for output in stack.outputs}

code_commit_access_key = outputs["AccessKeyForUser"]
code_commit_access_secret = outputs["SecretAccessKeyForUser"]
```

Please note that this could result in unexpected results if `stack.outputs` would contain multiple items with the same `OutputKey`, as you would only get the latest of such items represented in the dictionary. However I believe this isn't something to worry about in this particular case, as CloudFormation output value names have to be unique anyway.